# Django authentication with custom model User

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

For my needs builtin model User is not enough... So I have my own model UserProfile and I want make authentication on site through this model (UserProfile does not inherit from User model and not related to it at all).

My Model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 72, unique = True)

    ## Add this so that you can use request.user.is_authenticated
    def is_authenticated(self): 
        return True
```

But builtin authentication uses model User.

**So I want to understand how can I change that, so authentication use my model UserProfile with all auth features??**?

A good tutorial would be great!

(Step by step in views, models and authentication)

PS: I know I can store extra data in other model but I don't want that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an even more extreme example but illustrates that what you want to do can be done. The author not only replaces the User model which the authentication backend uses but also uses SQLAlchemy instead of the Django ORM. http://tomforb.es/using-a-custom-sqlalchemy-users-model-with-django

The main point is that you need to write your backend `authenticate` and `get_user` methods to retrieve your custom User model. If you want to also support permissions you would need to write `has_perm`.

Comment: This helped me allot. I was working in the right direction. Only thing i forgot was to add `def is_authenticated(self): return True` in my UserProfile model. See above